# Loading Window Size Issue

Tags: php, javascript, href

This is the code to pop up a new browser window.

```
 <A HREF="#" onClick="popup = window.open('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/agency/load_loc/', 'PopupPage', 'height=650,width=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>Images/next.jpg"  style="width:86px;" /></A>
```

Here i give the brwoser window width and height.But when pop uping the brwoser pop up window is in maximum size.

How can i slove this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once clear browser catch and then try

some time when we maximize the popup than javascript load that old window every time so it happened

Comment: i tried your code in my pc like <A HREF="#" onClick="popup = window.open('http://www.google.com', 'PopupPage', 'height=650,width=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false" target="_blank">Hello</A>  and its working fine...